# Can't delete a file using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I used the following codes but i am unable to delete the file. Can anyone help?

```
public class Delete{

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final Thread a = new Thread();
        a.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        final String fileName = "default\\sample.txt";

        // A File object to represent the filename

        final File f = new File(fileName);

        // Make sure the file or directory exists and isn't write protected

        if(!f.exists()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(

            "Delete: no such file or directory: " + fileName);
        }

        if(!f.canWrite()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: "

            + fileName);
        }

        // If it is a directory, make sure it is empty

        if(f.isDirectory()){

            final String[] files = f.list();

            if(files.length > 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(

                "Delete: directory not empty: " + fileName);
            }

        }

        // Attempt to delete it

        f.delete();

    }

}
```

Or is there any other way to delete a file using threads?

Comment: Indent, read about Thread basics and come back. You'll be able to delete.

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://www.java-forums.org/threads-synchronization/40088-cant-delete-file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
public class Delete extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread a = new Delete();

        a.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you re-post the code in the question with formatting? How does that help? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you're right. Apart from the `extends Thread` part, there's nothing different!

Comment: @Michael - Not me! The original author added it to his question :)

Answer (score 0):

The method run() is not called

```
import java.io.File;

public class Delete extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Delete a = new Delete();
        a.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\temp\\todelete.txt";
        File f = new File(fileName);
        if (!f.exists())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: no such file or directory: " + fileName);
        if (!f.canWrite())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: " + fileName);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            String[] files = f.list();
            if (files.length > 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: directory not empty: " + fileName);
        }

        boolean success = f.delete();

        if (!success)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to start your thread with:

```
Thread a = new Thread(new Delete());
a.start();
```

**Update:**

Your `Delete` class also needs to implement `Runnable`.

Comment: Ahh, missed that. It does have `run()` though.