# Delete file using C# Thread

Tags: c#

I was reading this article ([Can't delete a file using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217949/cant-delete-a-file-using-threads)) about my problem but things are getting difficult to me.

My problem is really simple, I just want to delete this old file, if I start the method "dlMoveNovaVersao" normally the file is deleted but if I put this on a thread (like bellow) I got "You are not allow". Someone knows what's the problem? (I wanna use thread).

```
    private void verificaVersaoSupervisor_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread threadConexao = new Thread(threadVerificaConexao);
        threadConexao.Start();
    }

    public void threadVerificaConexao()
    {
        try
        {
            Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com.br");
            if (verificaVersao())
            {
                try
                {
                    verificaKillSupervisor();
                    dlMoveNovaVersao();
                    Application.Exit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit(); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    public void dlMoveNovaVersao()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile("Anywebsite", @"c:\temp\supervisor.exe);
        try
        {
            File.Delete(@"c:\Test\supervisor.exe); //This file is always there!
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

Just discribe the purpose, My program (Supervisor Starter) check on website if I have an old version of "Supervisor" running (using XML), If it's true my "Supervisor Starter" verify if there is a process called "Supervisor" running and kill it after that "Supervisor Starter" download the new version and run it. (The program is small and the update don't take more then 4 seconds).

The problem start when my "Supervisor Starter" try delete the old version of my program. If I use thread I receive "I haven't permission to access the file", if I use the same method on Form class the file is deleted.

Comment: People may often have this issue, it's a classic threading question imho, and as such its good to see this level of question here.

Answer (score 4):

**I suspect that you're running the thread while the file is in use**. When the thread runs, it runs in parallel with the current thread. Have you ensured that that file is closed?.

Otherwise I think that the thread maybe being created with a credentials that are not yours. But I'm pretty sure this is not the case.

See if this is different for each case

```
catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User {0}. Message {1}", 
                         System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, 
                         err.Message);
    }
```

Comment: agreed, either of the two I think. I wonder whats so good about this question though.

Comment: Preet, my file was closed. The system said "I don't have permission"

Answer (score 0):

This is my functions for deleting files in threads if the files are in used

```
private static void Delete(System.IO.FileInfo file)
    {
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            int Attempt = 0;
            bool ShouldStop = false;
            while (!ShouldStop)
            {
                if (CanDelete(file))
                {
                    file.Delete();
                    ShouldStop = true;
                }
                else if (Attempt >= 3)
                {
                    ShouldStop = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // wait one sec
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                Attempt++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool CanDelete(System.IO.FileInfo file)
    {
        try
        {
            //Just opening the file as open/create
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                //If required we can check for read/write by using fs.CanRead or fs.CanWrite
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            //check if message is for a File IO
            string __message = ex.Message.ToString();
            if (__message.Contains("The process cannot access the file"))
                return true;
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Juidan, thanks for the help but the file was not in use, before this code I filled an array with all process and shutdown "supervisor" (It's working I've double check that).